# upgrading React script from 1.x to 3.x breaks sass variables (font awesome)

Tags: reactjs, sass, font-awesome, react-scripts

Im using a react resume template for my portfolio site.
Everything worked fine when i was on react-script 1.x.

Yesterday I updated my site to use a three.js animation, and when trying to deploy the site I got a fail to minify error.  I updated to "react-scripts": "3.4.1"

After updating react-scripts, I got an error to install node-sass, which i did.

And now I have a sass variable error.

```
SassError: Undefined variable: "$fa-css-prefix".
        on line 3 of /home/tom/Desktop/lighthouse/react-resume-template/public/css/font-awesome/scss/_fixed-width.scss
>> .#{$fa-css-prefix}-fw {
```

I know basically nothing about sass and css variables... and importing these things.  I don't actually see any import statements other than in the main font-awesome.scss so I'm kind of lost.

font-awesome.scss

```
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "path";
@import "core";
@import "larger";
@import "fixed-width";
@import "list";
@import "bordered-pulled";
@import "spinning";
@import "rotated-flipped";
@import "stacked";
@import "icons";
```

_fixed-width.scss

```
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-fw {
  width: (18em / 14);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've reported it sounds like:

A) you upgraded unrelated library X (react-scripts)

B) this forced you to upgrade library Y (node-sass)

C) now library Z (font-awesome) isn't working because of the upgrade to Y

While I don't know the specifics of each library, it's very possible that the problem is you have an old library Z, relative to your new library Y.  If that's the case, simply doing:

```
npm rm font-awesome
npm i font-awesome
```

should give you the latest font-awesome ... and given that it is a pretty popular library, that new version *likely* will work with the latest node-sass.